# Estimate for Poisson's equation

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations

Given Poisson's equation for a ball $B_r\subset\mathbb{R}^n$
\begin{align*}
\Delta u  &= 0 ~~~\text{in } B_r \\
u &= g~~~\text{in } \partial B_r,
\end{align*}
$g\in C^{\infty}$. Is it possible to show the following estimate

> $$
> \int_{B_r} |\nabla u|^2 dx \leq c \int_{\partial B_r} u^2dS~?
> $$

EDIT: 
the estimate does not have to hold for all $g$. I am interessed if there are $g$ so that the estimate holds. I think this was not clear.

Comment: For every $g$ you can find a constant $c_g$ such that the inequality holds. But this is typically not useful. What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 3):

No this is not possible. The trace of an $H^1$ function belongs to $L^p(\partial B_r)$ for some $p > 2$ (depending on the dimension $n$). Hence, your inequality would imply
$$
c_1 \, \| u \|_{L^p(\partial B_r)}
\le \| u \|_{H^1(B_r)}
\le c_2 \, \|u\|_{L^2(\partial B_r)}
$$
for some constants $c_1,c_2 > 0$ and all harmonic $u \in C^\infty(\bar B_r)$.
However, this cannot be true.

Comment: why would it implie this for all $u\in C^\infty$? Only for those solving the Equation or?

Comment: Yes, it is only true for harmonic $u$.

Comment: I am sorry I can not follow your argument. Setting $g=0$ we get $u=0$ so the inequallity you mentioned holds. So the answer must depend on $g$.